# Submitting a form with only a text field

Tags: 7, forms

I may be missing something obvious, but it appears my form's submit function isn't being run by simply submitting text into my textfield (via. enter).  Do I need to add the submit button to get this behavior?  Is there a workaround so I don't have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for basic forms you need to include a submit button for the submit function to be called.

Read more about the [Form API for Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7)

Comment: Basic forms?  Elaborate a bit, please.

Comment: By basic I meant "non-AJAX" in which I am not positive if you need the submit button or not.  Take a look at the [AJAX Forms in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/752056)